{auth_token} not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: Bearer {auth_token}
I am creating a aws API Gateway to call my Lambda function. I have created an authentication key that is checked in the lambda function I created but I keep getting this error: {auth_token} not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: Bearer {auth_token}. I am calling the api function through axios using this:
const axios = require('axios');

const apiGatewayUrl = 'url';
const authToken = 'auth';

const headers = {
  'Authorization':`Bearer ${authToken}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

const requestData = {
  blah = blah
};

async function invokeLambda() {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: apiGatewayUrl,
      headers: headers,
      data: requestData,
    });
    console.log('Status Code:', response.status);
    console.log('Response Body:', response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.error('Error Status:', error.response.status);
      console.error('Error Data:', error.response.data);
    } else if (error.request) {
      console.error('No response received:', error.request);
    } else {
      console.error('Error:', error.message);
    }
  }
}

invokeLambda();

The API trigger works when I try it in the api gateway testing but not when I do it through axios.  I know the function call is going through because the API cloudwatch is showing something trying to connect but I get a: {auth_token} not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: Bearer {auth_token}.

'Bearer {authToken}'  is this literally what you have? Looks to me like you are trying to use a template literal but you're using the wrong quotes and missing the $

This question is similar to: String interpolation in JavaScript?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

FYI Axios by default adds the content-type header based on the data type. You don't need to add it manually

It looks like your headers are not getting interpolated (it's not replacing {auth_token} with the value of your auth token variable).
Try changing this line:
 'Authorization':'Bearer {authToken}',
to:
'Authorization':`Bearer ${authToken}`,

The backtics(`) tell JavaScript to replace things in the string and the dollar sign ($) needs to come before the squiggly bracket {

I am still getting the same error.

@craazii what does your authToken look like?

random letters(random capitalization) and numbers. ie: Hjd3jsoFIEKN341agSgr8r

@craazii from the error message, AWS is expecting a key=value pair in the auth header.  Your lambda function might not be set up to use Bearer token authentication.  Here is what I found for using auth headers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html it's a very different format that what you're providing.  You may need to either update what you're sending to match, or see if you can change your auth method on the lambda function to expect a bearer token
